# How to init NSInputStream with a part of file?

Tags: iphone, ios, youtube, asihttprequest, nsstream

I was woking on YouTube Resumable Uploads: https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_resumable_uploads#Sending_a_Resumable_Upload_API_Request

I use ASIHttpRequest to upload the videos. 
For a direct uploading, I can use this method.

```
- (void)appendPostDataFromFile:(NSString *)file
```

But for an resume uploading, I can't append post data from the whole video file. 
Maybe I can write a method like this:

```
- (void)appendPostDataFromFile:(NSString *)file offset:(long long)offset
```

But I don't know how to make it work. Any help will be appreciated!
And here is the code from ASIHttpRequest:

```
- (void)appendPostDataFromFile:(NSString *)file
{
    [self setupPostBody];
    NSInputStream *stream = [[[NSInputStream alloc] initWithFileAtPath:file] autorelease];
    [stream open];
    NSUInteger bytesRead;
    while ( !_isTryCanceled && [stream hasBytesAvailable] ) {
        unsigned char buffer[1024*256];
        bytesRead = [stream read:buffer maxLength:sizeof(buffer)];
        if (bytesRead == 0) {
            break;
        }
        if ([self shouldStreamPostDataFromDisk]) {
            [[self postBodyWriteStream] write:buffer maxLength:bytesRead];
        } else {
            [[self postBody] appendData:[NSData dataWithBytes:buffer length:bytesRead]];
        }
    }
    [stream close];
}
```

As the code show above, if I can get a seekable NSInputStream, the problem will be solved. Is it possible to do so?

Comment: i haven't tried. might you can try to use NSFileHandle to seek and get bytes step by step.